# how to input clingo variable

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I have following code, but I want to change the variable of p, how can I do it?

```
{p(1;2;3;4)}.
:- p(X*2).
```

It is normal.
But the following code does'nt work.

```
p(1;2;3;4)

{p(X)} :- X = p(X).
:- p(X*2).
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP truth values do not change over time, either atoms are `true` or `false` for a specific answer set, they can not be overwritten. However you are free to introduce auxiliary predicates, for example:

```
p(1;2;3;4).
{q(X)} :- p(X).
:- q(X*2).
#show q/1.
```

The last line limits the output to just show the predicate `q` with arity `1`. Output:

```
Answer: 1

Answer: 2
q(3)
Answer: 3
q(1)
Answer: 4
q(1) q(3)
SATISFIABLE
```